# Remove "required" status from the Date field

Tags: entities, datetime, 7

I have a field that is currently marked as required.  However, I want this to be required for all roles but the Admin.  I've made a module that implements `hook_form_alter()`, and I have been able to remove the required status for all fields but the Date fields.  Any idea what settings I need to change?

Also, I've tried altering it in `hook_form_alter()`, as well as doing it in the '#after_build'. I had no luck there either.

Comment: This is a good question. The intuitive form logic does not apply. I believe this is because the date system checks back in with the main content definition to see if there should be a "to" date, and whether or not that too is required. The answer is likely in the internals of date.module.

Answer (score 3):

This is most probably because you don't just use a simple datefield, but one provided by e.g. the Date Module.

You should make sure that the module implementing your custom `hook_form_alter` runs last. That way, no other module can change it back to "required" again.

Furthermore, some modules implement a different "required" allthogether. E.g. the business-logic "if start-date is set then end-date is required too" cannot be implemented with simple "required" flags but will fire on the `hook_validations` for that form.

To override that, you will need to either exclude certain validations from running, by removing them from the [`element_validate`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#element_validate) or from the entire forms `#validate`.

You might want to replace these original validations with your own copies, to be sure you don't change ugly behaviour.